# NSImage not centered in image well

Tags: objective-c, nsimage

I'm loading a NSImage into an image well from a url.  Image load in but in the off center, in upper right corner of the image well.  When I resize the window the image centers itself.  Anyone familiar with why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found that xcode was loading an old nib file for whatever dumb reason.  Run clean under product menu then debug your issue.  I had to change the objects in my nib file around and now the images are centered.